# Mysql 8.0 - Calculating Moving Average

Tags: mysql, rolling-average

Currently, I'm working on a database on Amazons rds platform, and i'm connecting through mysql server.

At some point, I need to perform a rolling average of the form:

```
SELECT
id, x_axis,time,
AVG(x_axis) OVER (ORDER BY time
ROWS BETWEEN 8 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING)
AS running_average
FROM falla_machinedata
ORDER BY id;
```

The error I get is the following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near '(ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN 8 PRECEDING AND 0
FOLLOWING)AS running_aver' at line 3
```

I've tried with different tutorials to perform this operation, and the result is always the same. I always get a syntax error.

Can you help me figure out what if the problem here?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are probably not on mysql version 8 or above.

Comment: This shouldn't be generating an error, assuming your version of MySQL supports this window function syntax.  Please check AWS and make sure you're really using MySQL 8+.

Comment: I checked, and I have locally installes MySQL 8+, but Amazon RDS only supports MySQL 5+ (when i connect remotely to the amazon rds database, the console shows version
    Server version: 5.6.39-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Is there any way around this?